# Wordpress PHP: Conditional Statement wihtin a Conditional Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

How would I place the following:

```
<?php if (function_exists('premium_slider')){ premium_slider(1); }; ?>
```

Within the echo of this:

```
<?php if(is_page(2)){ echo ''; } ?>
```

Obviously I can't do this:

```
<?php if(is_page(2)){ echo '<?php if (function_exists('premium_slider')){ premium_slider(1); }; ?>'; } ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
   if (is_page(2) && function_exists('premium_slider')){ echo premium_slider(1); }; 
?>
```

---

With else:

```
 if (is_page(2) && function_exists('premium_slider')) {
      echo premium_slider(1);
  } else {
      echo "SO Rocks!";
  }
```

Alternatively:

```
echo is_page(2) && function_exists('premium_slider') ? premium_slider(1) : 'SO Rocks!';
```

Comment: If i wanted to add and else to that how would I add it?

Comment: @Guy: `if (condition) { statement1; } else { statement2;}`

Comment: +1 but I would split the check into two If statements instead of checking two conditions at the same time... IOW, check if we're on page 2 first, then check if the function exists, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if (is_page(2) && function_exists('premium_slider')) {
    echo premium_slider(1);
}

?>
```

Comment: This is what I now have, still having issues: `<?php if (is_page(2) && function_exists('premium_slider')) { echo premium_slider(1); else premium_slider(2); } ?>`

Comment: See JRL's comment above, your if() has syntax errrors. The general format is `if (conditions) { truecase } else { falsecase }`. you're missing the bracketing around `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code exactly:

```
<?php
    if (is_page(2) && function_exists ( 'premium_slider' )) { 
        echo premium_slider ( 1 );
    } else premium_slider ( 2 ); 
?>
```

You are using closing } at wrong place.